# when i start a template, how can i select a instance from awx Instance Groups quickly

Tags: ansible-awx

I need to use a playbook to install applications on servers in various regions around the world, for safety reasons, I must isolate all VPC in each region. If i set more Instance Groups on awx, i must be select Instance Groups on start Templates, every time!!! it is terrible and slow, i think, if set a var equal to instance or instance group in hosts, and then when i start playbook, the will automatically select based on the instance I set.

someone know that how to set?

I have searched for many documents, but most of them have not answered my questions. I just don't want to repeat some operations every time I start the template

Answer (score 0):

i was looking at the same thing..
I am in the process of deploying a few execution hosts.
i might be wrong.. but....
It seems the instances are selected at the inventory definitions context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).